# Character Issue with non-english characters in filename - Webcenter Content

Tags: character-encoding, jdeveloper, webcenter, oracle-ucm

I am using JDev 11g.
I need to upload files to Webcenter Content.
I use RIDC API to upload files and i can upload successfully.

The problem is that the characters which are non-english are being displayed corruptedly.

Is there any settings to set filename encoding as UTF8?

Many thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

File name looks like:   Avucunuzdaki Kelebek Full-split-[Part-1]-�_i��.mp4
in Webcenter Content. Normally it is Avucunuzdaki Kelebek Full-split-[Part-1]-üğşiçö.mp4

When i run the application locally on my integratedweblogicserver i can upload files with correct filenames. But in live Webcenter Portal project it uploads files with corrupted file names like above.

And the weird part is it happens if components uploads multiple files.
There is one more af:inputFile component in same page and it uploads files with non-english characters successfully.

You can see codes i use to upload below:

```
RIDCAdaptor ridc = new RIDCAdaptor();

DataBinder db =
    ridc.checkinByUploadedPermanent(ufp, dosyaAdi, "DigitalMedia",
                                    "Secure");

ridc.createFileLinkInFolder(ridc.getFolderGUID("/Portal/Portal_Yonetim/Portal_Sunumlar"),
                            db.getLocal("dDocName"), "owner");


public RIDCAdaptor() {
    super();
    idcClientManager = new IdcClientManager();
    idcContext =
            new IdcContext(ProjectUtils.getAdminusername(), ProjectUtils.getAdminpassw());
    idcClient = createIdcClient();
}

public IdcClient createIdcClient() {
    IdcClient idcClient = null;
    try {
        idcClient =
                idcClientManager.createClient(ProjectUtils.getWCCIDCAddressWithPort());
    } catch (IdcClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    idcClient.getConfig().setSocketTimeout(10000); // 30 secods
    idcClient.getConfig().setConnectionSize(20); // 20 connections
    return idcClient;
}

public DataBinder checkinByUploadedPermanent(UploadedFilePermanent uploadedFilePermanent,
                                             String docTitle,
                                             String docType,
                                             String securityGroup) {
    BlobDomain blobDomain = uploadedFilePermanent.getBlobDomain();
    DataBinder dataBinder = idcClient.createBinder();
    dataBinder.putLocal("IdcService", "CHECKIN_UNIVERSAL");
    dataBinder.putLocal("dDocType", docType);
    dataBinder.putLocal("dDocTitle", docTitle);
    dataBinder.putLocal("dDocAuthor", idcContext.getUser());
    dataBinder.putLocal("dDocAccount", "");
    dataBinder.putLocal("dSecurityGroup", securityGroup);
    dataBinder.putLocal("xClbraRoleList", ":authenticated(R)");
    dataBinder.addFile("primaryFile",
                       new TransferFile(blobDomain.getInputStream(),
                                        docTitle, blobDomain.getLength(),
                                        uploadedFilePermanent.getUploadedFile().getContentType()));
    ServiceResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = idcClient.sendRequest(idcContext, dataBinder);
    } catch (IdcClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DataBinder asBinder = null;
    try {
        asBinder = response.getResponseAsBinder();
    } catch (IdcClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return asBinder;
}
```

Comment: How do you know they are being corrupted? Is the file size in WebCenter Content the same as the file you uploaded? Can you share a link to your RIDC code?

Comment: What happens if you upload the same file interactively?

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys. Topic is updated.